# Calculate rows per id and per period Month and Year

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I want to show a DataGridView with Compte Name and total sum of Recette and Depense per month and year.
I have a DateTimePicker customized with month an year.[Image of the Winforms and the error](http://s27.postimg.org/pi0wjbcsz/tutu.png)

Example : if I select date = 11/2015 (November 2015), it will show like that

```
Compte  Total   
BTK     633,000
Biat    987,888
Caisse  988,875
```

and if I select date = 06/2016 (Jun 2016), it will show like that

```
Compte  Total   
BTK     0
Biat    653,256
Caisse  88,145
```

**My Code :**

```
public partial class ComptesMois : Form
{
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand comm;
    SqlDataReader dreader;
    string connstring = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Tresorerie;Integrated Security=True";
    public ComptesMois()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Set Columns Count
        DataGridViewCompteMois.ColumnCount = 2;

        //Hide the last blank line
        DataGridViewCompteMois.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

        //Add Columns
        DataGridViewCompteMois.Columns[0].Name = "NomCom";
        DataGridViewCompteMois.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Nom de Compte";
        DataGridViewCompteMois.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "NomCom";
        DataGridViewCompteMois.Columns[0].Width = 100;

        //Add Columns
        DataGridViewCompteMois.Columns[1].Name = "Total";
        DataGridViewCompteMois.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Total";
        DataGridViewCompteMois.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Total";
        DataGridViewCompteMois.Columns[1].Width = 100;

        this.BindGrid();

        CompteMoisdateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        CompteMoisdateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "MM yyyy";
        //CompteMoisdateTimePicker.ShowUpDown = true; // to prevent the calendar from being displayed

    }

    private void BindGrid()
    {

        DataGridViewCompteMois.DataSource = null;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT c.NomCom from Tresorerie t join Compte c on t.IdCom=c.IdCom", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        DataGridViewCompteMois.DataSource = dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void DataGridViewCompteMois_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string month = CompteMoisdateTimePicker.Value.Month.ToString();
        string year = CompteMoisdateTimePicker.Value.Year.ToString();
        //select * from < table > where month(searchDate) = Month_from_box and Year(searchDate) = Year_from_box
        // select sum(recette + depence) from Tresorerie where 
        String total;

        for (int i = 0; i < DataGridViewCompteMois.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
            conn.Open();
            String NomCompteDataGrid = Convert.ToString(DataGridViewCompteMois.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
            String IdCompteValue = "select IdCom from Compte where NomCom='" + NomCompteDataGrid + "'";
            comm = new SqlCommand(IdCompteValue, conn);
            int IdComValue = Convert.ToInt32(comm.ExecuteScalar());
            conn.Close();

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstring))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select sum(Recette + Depense) as Total from Tresorerie where IdCom=@IdCom GROUP BY Recette,Depense", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdCom", IdComValue);
                    con.Open();
                    total = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            DataGridViewCompteMois.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = total;
        }
    }
}
```

but there is an error, the result show me -1 for every Compte

Update 1: Thanks to @Soner_Gönül, I modify the query statement, and I tested it on sql and it works, but the problem when I add the result to the grid cell, it shows empty, but I try to show it with messgae box and it works, my code :

```
 String total;
    private void CompteMoisdateTimePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string month = CompteMoisdateTimePicker.Value.Month.ToString();
        string year = CompteMoisdateTimePicker.Value.Year.ToString();


        for (int i = 0; i < DataGridViewCompteMois.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
            conn.Open();
            String NomCompteDataGrid = Convert.ToString(DataGridViewCompteMois.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
            String IdCompteValue = "select IdCom from Compte where NomCom='" + NomCompteDataGrid + "'";
            comm = new SqlCommand(IdCompteValue, conn);
            int IdComValue = Convert.ToInt32(comm.ExecuteScalar());
            conn.Close();

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstring))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select SUM( Depense + Recette ) from Tresorerie where IdCom=@IdCom and MONTH(DateTre) = @MONTH AND YEAR(DateTre) = @YEAR GROUP BY IdCom", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdCom", IdComValue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MONTH", month);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YEAR", year);
                    con.Open();
                    total = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            DataGridViewCompteMois.Rows[i].Cells["Total"].Value = total;
            //MessageBox.Show(total.ToString());
        }
    }
```

**Update Solution: look I have a problem which cell selected, this code works**

```
private void CompteMoisdateTimePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string month = CompteMoisdateTimePicker.Value.Month.ToString();
        string year = CompteMoisdateTimePicker.Value.Year.ToString();
        for (int i = 0; i < DataGridViewCompteMois.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
            conn.Open();
            String NomCompteDataGrid = Convert.ToString(DataGridViewCompteMois.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
            String IdCompteValue = "select IdCom from Compte where NomCom='" + NomCompteDataGrid + "'";
            comm = new SqlCommand(IdCompteValue, conn);
            int IdComValue = Convert.ToInt32(comm.ExecuteScalar());
            conn.Close();

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstring))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select SUM( Depense + Recette ) from Tresorerie where IdCom=@IdCom and MONTH(DateTre) = @MONTH AND YEAR(DateTre) = @YEAR GROUP BY IdCom", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdCom", IdComValue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MONTH", month);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YEAR", year);
                    con.Open();
                    //MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar()));
                    DataGridViewCompteMois.Rows[i].Cells["Total"].Value = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is using `ExecuteNonQuery` with a `SELECT` statement since;

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. **For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1**.

Looks like you need to use `ExecuteScalar` as well to get total of your `Recette + Depense` columns.

Comment: @Juste3alfaz That means your `select sum(Recette + Depense) as Total from Tresorerie where IdCom=@IdCom GROUP BY Recette,Depense` statement returns an empty result. Have you ever check this query on sql server and see it _really_ returns some data?